Safely write RDS files in parallel
I do parallel computation from data in R, with 2000 parallel jobs, I use the following code in each job to save the final results in RDS format:
timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    timestamp <- paste0(timestamp, sample.int(1000, 1))
    filename <- paste0("differences_", timestamp, ".rds")
    saveRDS(differences, file = filename)

I realized that even though I added random four-digits to the time stamp, it might still be possible that the parallel jobs conflicting each other. A possible solution could be to check whether a file with the same name already existed, if so generate a new name:
while (file.exists(filename)) {
  timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  timestamp <- paste0(timestamp, sample.int(1000, 1))
  filename <- paste0("differences_", timestamp, ".rds")
}

But I am not sure if this is entirely safe. Is there a way to ensure a unique file name for each result from the parallel jobs? I have to keep the files in the same path.

My approach in the past has been to check if the filename already exists (and regenerate the name if it does exist). With many random characters, timestamp and assuming writing of the file is relatively short, name clash is unlikely. If you would want a fail safe way of generating the filenames, you could construct a database of suffixes in advance and exhaust them sequentially. Complexity of setting up all the infrastructure for this may not be warranted as filename clash is unlikely.

@RomanLuštrik I think I could make the random digits longer, lowering the possibility of  filename clashing to an acceptable extent.

You could add a UUID to the filename, using the uuid-package.

In a nutshell, this approach is completely unsafe (checking file existence before write is a classic race condition scenario, and the birthday paradox teaches us that using simple random filenames will lead to surprisingly frequent collisions!), and also needlessly complex: instead, generate unique, sequential filenames in the main process and pass individual paths into the subprocesses when launching them.

@Wimpel I checked the package, from my understanding this is a complex random character generator, it is extremely hard to clash but not entirely impossible?

@KonradRudolph This is a good approach. According to my tests there are indeed 20% of the results missing, probably oweing to clashing names

I never trust random characters to avoid namespace collision (such as filenames of parallel jobs); having it as a component is fine so long as there are sufficient other components. I prefer Konrad's suggestion of sequential filenames for this, but if you don't know ahead of time how many you will produce, then an alternative is the maildir file naming, where I think the pivotal components are: epoch nanoseconds, the PID of the writing process, and a per-process counter.

On a related note: Saving/writing takes time, and sometimes gets interrupted or fail, risking leaving behind an incomplete *.rds file. This will eventually hit you when you run lots of tasks, especially in HPC environments. I use something like saveRDS(..., file = "foo.rds.tmp") followed by file.rename("foo.rds.tmp","foo.rds") to emulate writing the foo.rds file atomically - that way I know the *.rds is complete if I see it.

I'll offer this as a slightly-more-complex variant of @KonradRudolph's suggestion (pre-sequence filenames for each parallel task), which is far simpler and might be preferable in most situations.
This suggestion is geared towards shared-filesystems where filenames cannot be easily pre-determined. The problems with shared-filesystems start from the basis that using existing files for uniqueness is a guaranteed race-condition theoretically, somewhat reproducibly bad on a local filesystem, and with NFS and other shared filesystems the lag can produce significant problems. So we need to produce a filename "in real time" that has so-very-low likelihood of collision. (In my example, I write to a Luster filesystem, where file-creation-lag can be upwards of 5-10 seconds across nodes on the HPC.)
Here's a function that will produce such a filename:
#' Create a "guaranteed-unique" filename
#'
#' @param path character, the directory in which the new file will be
#'   created
#' @param fileext optional character, appended to the new filename
#' @param create logical, whether to "touch" the file
#' @return character, the filename, optionally created
#' @export
unique_filename <- local({
  .host <- gsub("[/:]", "_", Sys.info()["nodename"])
  .count <- 0L

  function(path = character(0), fileext = "", create = FALSE) {
    now <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    # if we put this up with `.host`, I suspect the `future` is
    # transferring the old PID to new processes
    .pid <- Sys.getpid()
    # we look within all subdirs to make sure we won't have a "future"
    # collision (though highly unlikely) and then discard the
    # subdirectory component
    filename <- sprintf(
      "%0.06f.P%i.Q%i.%s%s",
      now, .pid, .count, .host, fileext)
    .count <<- .count + 1L
    out <- if (length(path) && nzchar(path)) file.path(path, filename) else filename
    if (create) fs::file_touch(out)
    out
  }
})

It is based heavily on the file naming convention used in Maildir mail storage, where NFS-based file conflicts had to be avoided as inexpensively as possible. I do not use all of the suggested components, so this implementation is weakened slightly. In my use with thousands of concurrent writes, I have seen no collisions.
It uses:

epoch microseconds
hostname
process ID (pid)
an internal counter for each process

One side-effect of the filename starting with a "time" component is that the files naturally sort chronologically, if that's appealing. The use of random filenames (uuid or otherwise) does not do this as easily.
